# Android Osmdroid get poins of interest from own database

Tags: java, android, overlay, offline, osmdroid

This is my first time using stackoverflow because I am really desperate to solve this issue.

I am developing an app that contains information about bus stops in my country (Google maps does not work if I try to go from X to Y on a bus) so I decided to do it myself. I already tracked every stop of many buses.

I show each bus stop as overlays in my osmdroid map view, I get this information from a internal database that as I said I collected the information and is not online.

What I want to do now, is to get the user's location (lat, long) and tell him/her the closets bus stops to him/her location. I already looked at Osmdroid bonuspack and the POI feature, but what I understood is that these places (restaurants, bus stops, hospitals, etc) are already on a server.

How can I implement a POI function on my application with local information. I would appreciate any help, this is something I want to do for my community.

Thank you everyone and sorry for my poor English. I am doing my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the coordinates of bus stops in your database, and they are displayed in an overlay. You can also get the current users location. What you want to achieve is a matter of calculating the [geographical distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance) between two points (the user's location and a bus stop).

You don't have to implement a suitable formula yourself, e.g. have a look at the [`GeoPoint`](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/util/GeoPoint.java) class. There's a `distanceTo(final IGeoPoint other)` method. You can instantiate a `GeoPoint` with known coordinates or simply use Overlay methods.

You could also achieve the same thing by querying only the bus stops that are within a certain radius of the user's location (maybe have a look at the [`BoundingBox`](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/util/BoundingBoxE6.java))

If you want to use libraries like the BonusPack, look at the provider implementations. You could simply write your own provider for your bus stops. Have a look at e.g. [this](https://github.com/sibext/OSMBonusPack/blob/master/src/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/location/NominatimPOIProvider.java) one.

Comment: distanceTo method is just what I needed I guess I did not check enough. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
  > How can I implement a POI function on my 
  > application with local information
```

I assume that your question is about "how to render busstops on local device" and not "how to query my local database" and not "how to do some server-side support."

If you want to render the busstops on you local android device you can use [osmbonuspack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack)

which contain an [example app](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/master/OSMBonusPackTuto/src/com/example/osmbonuspacktuto/MainActivity.java) that shows how to render interactive poi-s.

Unfortunately currently there is no precompiled osmbonuspack aar at jcenter/mavencentral so you have to include the sources as a local subdirectory of your project.